# Files not copied to build output

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I have everything running fine in ripple but I'm now trying to build for iOS.  Getting a Mac set up at the moment is not an option so I'm following the instructions on [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859242.aspx) to create a phonegap project and then use phonegap build.  This was working fine but today the bld\Debug folder only contains the default cordova app, never my files.

I've created a new cordova app from scratch and the index.html in the build output is the default cordova one there too, not even the default one provided in the vs template.

I've tried cleaning the cordova cache and rebuilding, all to no avail.

The build output looks like this

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp1, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation, so it will skip compiling.
1>  GeneratedJavascript=
1>  E:\projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat 
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\SJY0AUOG.SG4\packages\vs-mda
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This seems to be missing a whole bunch of "copying files" around info that I used to get.  What could be going wrong?